# Linear Recurrence Using matrix exponentiation

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations, exponentiation

Matrix Exponentiation can be used to solve Linear Recurrence .
I know how to solve linear recurrences like :

$f(n) = f(n-k_1) + f(n-k_2) + ... +\ constant$

But i couldn't find any information on how to solve recurrences like

$f(n) = f(n-k_1) + f(n-k_2) + ... + n^m$

or

$f(n) = f(n-k_1) + f(n-k_2) + ... + n\cdot m$

or

$f(n) = f(n-k_1) + f(n-k_2) + ... + k^n$

i.e.

involving an '$n$' term.

> Can anyone provide me with any link or explain how to solve such recurrences
>   or how to form the initial matrix whose power will be used to solve the recurrence?

This is required in :

http://www.spoj.com/problems/ASUMHARD/

Answer (score 1):

For $k^n$ just place $k$ in the first free diagonal element where all other on the same row are 0, you will find $k^n$ in that position in the exponentiated matrix:

$${\bf A} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}k&{\bf 0}^T \\ * & * \end{array}\right) \Rightarrow {\bf A}^n = \left(\begin{array}{cc}k^n&{\bf 0}^T \\ * & * \end{array}\right)$$

To get $mn$ and $n^m$ you can check my [answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349119/matrix-representations-and-polynomials).

In terms of recurrences which may be easier for you since you have already dealt with them this means to use the fact that $n+1 = 1+(n)$ (simplest possible recurrence), $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1$ et.c. I.e. binomial expansions of monomials.

Comment: Could u provide algorithm of the given spoj link. Just way to approach,tat would be nice

Comment: Well I guess you see that $f(n) = f(n-1) + n^k$