# How many move paths on a 2-d grid?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

On a 2-d grid how many different move paths can be made that begin at $(0,0)$ and end at $(x,y)$ with $x\gt 0$,$y\gt 0$. Restriction : left,down and diagonally moves aren't allowed .

Comment: So you can use only up and right moves right ??

Comment: Note that you will need a total of $x$ "Right" moves and a total of $y$ "Up" moves.  Reword the question to instead how many sequences of R's and U's exist with $x$ R's and $y$ U's.

Answer (score 0):

At each position except the boundaries we can go two different directions: "up" and "right".

At point ($x_0,y_0$) this is $f(x_0,y_0) =  f(x_0,y_0-1)+f(x_0-1,y_0)$. We also have the boundary conditions above that there is only one path along each boundary $f(k,1) = f(1,k) = 1$. We can now write a linear equation system to express $f(a,b)$ which we can solve with our favourite method.

---

However we have a **symmetry** of our problem which would allow us to simplify it a great deal if you have studied some more algebra. For simplifying using this symmetry we can take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349119/matrix-representations-and-polynomials) which uses matrix exponentiation to find the numbers. This can in some sense be compared to using the numerical conjugate-gradient scheme on the above equation system - which results in investigating the Krylov Subspace $\{Iv,Av,A^2v,\cdots,A^nv\}$ which is precisely what the exponentiation above does but in a more compact form.
In particular, we have the
$$A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\0&1&1\end{array}\right]$$
$$(A^{13})_{3,1} = 78 \hspace{0.5cm} \text{and} \hspace{0.5cm} nCr(13,2) = 78$$
Where nCr is the same function as Alex mentions in his answer. If we want to find a solution for larger grids we just need to increase the size of $A$ accordingly.